# copy std::vector<unsigned char> address to unsigned char[] array

Tags: c++, networking, char, stdvector, unsigned

I have a `vector` that receives bytes from the network:

`std:vector<unsigned char> data`

I am trying to copy the address of the `data` into an `unsigned char *[]` array:

`unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char [1024*1024]`

I want to loop through it to find a valid data packet that I am looking for. The sample code is below.

How do I copy the address of `data` into `buffer`?

header file:

```
typedef struct {
    uint word;
    int id;
    int nubBytes;
}Header;
    
#define WORD 0xA345
unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char[1024*1024];
Header *hdr;
int pktOffset;
```

cpp file:

```
Decode msg(std:vector<unsigned char> data, uint32_t bytesrcvd){
    pktOffset = 0;
    buffer = &data;
    rcvBufOffSet += bytesRcvd;
    numBytesInRecBuff += bytesRcvd;
    hdr = (Header *)(& buffer[pktOffset])
    if(hdr->word != WORD){    
        while(hdr->word != WORD && numBytesInRecBuff > 0)
            pktOffset++;
        numBytesInRecBuff--;
        hdr = (Header *)(& Buffer[pktOffset])
    }
    if(hdr->word != WORD){
        return;
    }
    else{
        //process packet data
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just read the data from the vector rather than copy it to a buffer to read.
I understand when you find a match you still need to copy the data from the vector to the structure.  Also the `if(hdr->word...` statement is not necessary as you currently have the code.

Comment: You don't want the address of `data` but the address of its contents, which is `data.data()`, not `&data`. And there is no point in copying anything.

Comment: On a side note, your code is very sensitive to endianness.

Comment: Your code is creating a memory leak.  You don't need the `new[]` at all.  Just process the `vector`'s data directly. Also, you should be passing the `vector` by reference to avoid making an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Remy Lebeau -  how to I print the value in buffer and its memory address when using std:vector<unsigned char>* buffer;  buffer = &data;

Comment: when I am using unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char[1024*1024]; I did buffer = &data[0]; and was copy the address of data to buffer. as mentioned above when using a std::vector as - std:vector<unsigned char>* buffer;  do I do this to copy the address of da to  buffer? buffer = &data;